# Is there a safe way to update a field in an audio queue's user data struct from outside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, locking, core-audio

I'm building a simple recorder for learning purposes using audio queues. 
The callback function receives a pointer to a struct which is defined like this:

```
typedef struct RecorderUserData {
    AudioFileID outputFileID;
    SInt64 recordPacket;
    BOOL recording;
} RecorderUserData;
```

Inside the callback function fields from this struct are accessed. This callback function gets called *asynchronously* by Core Audio.

```
static void RecorderAudioQueueInputCallback(void *inUserData, 
    AudioQueueRef inQueue,
    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
    const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime,
    UInt32 inNumPackets,
    const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDesc) {

    UXAudioRecorderUserData *recorderUserData = (UXAudioRecorderUserData *)inUserData;

    if (recorderUserData->recording) {
        // do something while recording
    }

    // much more code
}
```

The problem is, I want to start / stop recording from outside method calls. When recording starts, the struct is prepared with the recording field set to YES.

When recording must end, I must set the recording field to NO.

In the Core Audio book by Kevin Avila and Chris Adamson they do it all in a big monolithic main function where I have still access to this struct at the foot.

But since Core Audio is accessing this struct asynchronously, how can I safely set the recording field to NO once my -stopRecording method gets called? The problem is that I would probably need a pointer to this struct in my recorder class, but also a way of locking access to it so I don't change it to NO while the callback function is reading it.

Answer (score 0):

One should not wait on any locks inside a Core Audio callback.

One method to handle this is to use a simple atomic-write-sized (1 word) flag, that can only be written in one thread, and that is only read once in any other callbacks or methods.  Then, as long as the audio callback can't write the flag, and only reads it once at the beginning, it should be safe to toggle that flag from the main thread.  But note that the callback could still be "doing something" after the flag is toggled (and the data cache is flushed, etc.), so you may need to wait some period of time (the max audio unit buffer size), or for another completion handshake flag, before being sure that the change in your recording flag state was recognized.